# MySQL Multi Join

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I had a look at the other answers in relation to mysql join and am still a little confused as to whether i'm using it right for the right instance.

I have a query that I need to perform over multiple tables at the same time and keep getting told that my statement is ambiguous.

I have 4 tables... trecord, thours, torders and tphotos

The trecord table has it's own autonumber called bid, and all the other tables have their own autonumber as well as a bid column. The trecord table will only ever have one record that needs to be retrieved at a time as does the thours table, but the torders and tphotos table will more often than not have multiple records in them that will tie back to the trecord to always show the company info.

How can I bring together all the information from trecord and thours as well as all of the information from torders and tphotos that match the bid?

```
$id = isset($_POST['bid']) ? $_POST['bid'] : isset($_GET['bid']) ? $_GET['bid'] : null;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM torders
INNER JOIN trecord ON torders.bid=trecord.bid
INNER JOIN thours ON thours.bid=trecord.bid
INNER JOIN tphotos ON tphotos.bid=trecord.bid
FROM  WHERE bid='" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "'";
```

Comment: Does your query work? I don't see the query as being ambiguous if you actually want to get the information from each of those tables. Perhaps they thought the design of the table structure was ambiguous.

Comment: Chage those all to RIGHT JOIN

Comment: What's wrong with your code? (Other that you have an extra `FROM`)?

Comment: @AlienWebguy Why? *" tables have their own autonumber as well as a bid column"*. I don't see any mention of some items having `null` or missing data.

Comment: Hi Alien, tables have their own autonumber for the example of orders having their own order number and photos having their own photo number :-)

Comment: the exact words it comes back with are...

cannot run the query because: Column 'bid' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: Hi Spencer, How do you mean the design of the table structure is ambiguous? :-S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every table has a 'bid' column, you need to be more specific as to which one you are running your where clause against.

Comment: HAHAHA... You're awesome! All it took was to add the trecord.bid to the where clause!

Comment: Thanks. Good luck with the rest.